# Automating the process of importing project into eclipse workspace using command line interface not working as expected

Tags: eclipse, batch-file, jenkins, command-line, automation

I have command line argument for importing existing project into eclipse work space. But as soon as I try to execute it using windows batch file eclipse opens and starts loading and closes immediately. Here is the code that I am trying to run.

```
ECHO on
PUSHD 
SET ECLPSE=%cd%
SET WORKSPACE=%~dp0
POPD
SET PATH=%PATH%;%ECLPSE%\bin;
RD /s /q %ECLPSE%\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.app > Nul
RD /s /q %ECLPSE%\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi > Nul
RD /s /q %ECLPSE%\configuration\org.eclipse.update > Nul
START /B %ECLPSE%\bin\tresos_gui.exe -Dmsg1085=false -data %WORKSPACE% %*
START /B %ECLPSE%\bin\tresos_gui.exe importProject -c C:\Jenkins\jobs
```

This is the syntax for importing a project into the workspace.

```
tresos_cmd.bat [<system_property>...] [-data <workspace>] 
                           importProject [-c] <project path>...
```

Can someone please help me with this. I would really appreciate it. I have even combined last two statements in one line and tried executing it but it is of no use. My main aim is to automate the process of importing project into eclipse workspace so that software can be built using jenkins.

Comment: Anyone there to help me??

Answer (score 0):

All folder paths containing `%ECLPSE%` or `%WORKSPACE%` should be enclosed in double quotes in case of `%cd%` and/or `%~dp0` expand to a folder path with a space character or one of the characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``.

I did not really understand what is the goal of the batch file and what `tresos_gui.exe` is for.
However, here is an improved and commented batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

rem Path of current directory hold in environment variable CD usually does
rem not end with a backslash (directory separator on Windows). But if the
rem current directory is the root directory of a drive, the directory path
rem ends with a backslash. Assign current directory path to environment
rem variable ECLPSE (strange name) always without a trailing backslash.

if not "%CD:~-1%" == "\" ( set "ECLPSE=%CD%" ) else ( set "ECLPSE=%CD:~0,-1%" )

rem Path of batch file always ends with a backslash, but should be assigned
rem to environment variable WORKSPACE always without a trailing backslash.

set "WORKSPACE=%~dp0"
set "WORKSPACE=%WORKSPACE:~0,-1%"

rem The environment variable PATH can end with a folder path or with a
rem semicolon after last folder path. The subdirectory BIN in current
rem directory should be appended with an additional semicolon only if
rem environment variable PATH does not already end with a semicolon.

if "%PATH:~-1%" == ";" ( set "PATH=%PATH%%ECLPSE%\bin" ) else ( set "PATH=%PATH%;%ECLPSE%\bin" )

rem Command RD does not print any message on success. It prints only an error
rem message to handle STDERR if the directory tree could not be removed.

rd /Q /S "%ECLPSE%\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.app" 2>nul
rd /Q /S "%ECLPSE%\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi" 2>nul
rd /Q /S "%ECLPSE%\configuration\org.eclipse.update" 2>nul

rem Command START interprets first double quoted string as title for the
rem command process window. Therefore specify as first parameter just ""
rem which is an empty title string.

rem The start of tresos_gui.exe is done for some unknown reason in a separate
rem process in background. Hold execution of batch file until this separate
rem process terminated itself before running tresos_gui.exe a second time
rem to import the project and best wait again until this process terminated.

start "" /WAIT /B "%ECLPSE%\bin\tresos_gui.exe" -Dmsg1085=false -data "%WORKSPACE%" %*
start "" /WAIT /B "%ECLPSE%\bin\tresos_gui.exe" importProject -c C:\Jenkins\jobs

endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%*`
- `cmd /?` ... explains with last paragraph on last help page when double quotes are required.
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `if /?`
- `rd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`

And read also the Microsoft TechNet article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`.

Comment: When I try to run this script it says windows can't find this file \bin\tresos_gui.exe. Why is this happening.How can I overcome this error?

Comment: As `"%ECLPSE%\bin\tresos_gui.exe"` is equal `"%CD%\bin\tresos_gui.exe"` the real question is: What is the current directory on running this batch file because there is no subdirectory `bin` containing the executable `tresos_gui.exe` in current directory on running the batch file? You could use at at top the command line `echo CD=%CD% & pause` to see the current directory. Current directory is `%SystemRoot%` on running a batch file via UNC path. Current directory is `%SystemRoot%\System32` on running a batch file as administrator.

Comment: So inorder to avoid this error i have to change the path where this bat file exists.That had solved my problem. But still i am unable to import my projects into eclipse work space. It just launches eclipse but doesn't import projects automatically into eclipse. This batch file should launch eclipse and import projects into eclipse work space automatically. Can you please suggest me a way to do that. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have Eclipse installed and therefore can't help on new problem with importing projects into Eclipse workspace not working as expected by you.

Comment: As I have mentioned, the below mentioned syntax should be used to import projects onto eclipse workspace. Could you please help me with that                                                                                   tresos_cmd.bat [<system_property>...] [-data <workspace>] 
                           importProject [-c] <project path>...